# Why do definite articles seem implicit in English?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, french, uncountable-nouns

I was thinking about the translation for "life" (as in everyday living) in french which translates "vie". However, in spoken language you would always refer to "la vie" in french and never to "the life" in English.

How and why did English seem to make determiners implicit (or French explicit)?

Comment: It's called the definite article in English. No abstract word takes a definite article in English: life, death, happiness, sadness, etc. All those take one in French, and in all Romance languages.  It would only take a definite article with the OF, One Day in the Life of Ivan Denisovitch. (that's from memory).  He's living the life of Riley. But life is difficult. Or as we say, C'est la vie. [smile]

Comment: @Lambie - "The sadness was unbearable." "The life of a soldier is full of hardship," "The death of so many children sent a political shock through the country,"

Comment: @Lambie: Yes, but *how and why?*, is the question.

Comment: The French expression is "la vie" the English equivalent is "life", the song in French is "La Vie en Rose", in English it can be translated as "Life Through Rose-Tinted Glasses". It is not talking about a particular life, it is not a physical object which one can touch or see, "life" is a conception, an idea. But when we speak about a person's life or the life of a group, we use the article "The Life and Times of Henry VIII", "The life of Brian", "The life of birds".

Comment: As to "why" I have not the slightest clue, it just is. Why do French and Italian place the definite article for parts of the body, *la mano* (the hand) or for foods and drinks *Mi piace il vino* (I like the wine)?

Comment: The sadness [of (some situation)] is implied. Ergo, the /the/. The life OF a soldier. The death OF. I explained that with OF, the abstract noun will often take the. Sometimes the OF is implied as in the first example. It is the possessive that creates the need for the article....The Life of Brian. If you actually remove the OF, you get Brian's Life. Same meaning in fact but not the same style.

Comment: Please contrast: The sadness [of some particular situation] with: Sadness is unbearable. The of is implied....English is full of implied "stuff": that, of and nouns after some phrasal verbs. There are probably others...

Comment: It's because explicit language is so vulgar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do determiners seem implicit in English?

Because the definite article *the* is mainly used to **explicitly** identify or specify nouns that are *countable* such as *regular nouns*; dog, face, heart which is beating in a body and boy, etc. and *collective nouns*; family, nation, people, etc. It doesn't mean that countable nouns take only the definite article.

Other uncountable nouns are called a *mass noun* which includes an *abstract noun*. A mass noun doesn't take the indefinite article *a* or *an* as it is *uncountable*  and they sometimes take the definite article when it is specified or restricted. There are exceptions when they are used as a regular/countable nouns, e.g., "she is a beauty" which means "she is a beautiful woman" and "honesty is a virtue" which means "honesty is one of many virtues", etc.

Let's compare some examples using the sentences in the comment posted by @WhatRoughBeast.

> (1) The sadness was unbearable. vs I feel a sense of sadness.

The reason the definite article is used for the former is the *sadness* is 
felt by a specific person. The word *sadness* in the latter refers to the condition of being sad which is not specific nor restricted and is just a concept.

> (2) The life of a soldier is full of hardship vs Life is full of hope.

The reason the definite article is used for the former is the *life* is restricted/modified by *of a soldier* and it is specific and different from your and my life. *Life* and *hope* in the latter are a mass noun which doesn't require the definite article because of the same reason as explained above for *sadness* (not specific nor restricted).

> (3) The death of so many children sent a political shock through the
>   country. vs I am scared of death.

The reason is same as No (2). The *death* in the former is restricted/modified by *of so many children* and *death* is not specific in the latter. Everybody is afraid to die and death applies to everyone who can't see nor experience it. It is as abstract as it gets.

> The heart of a human being vs They had change of heart.

The heart in the former means a human organ and it is a countable noun. We have only one heart. However, the word *heart* in the latter is an abstract noun which means *one's mood or feeling*. That's why it doesn't take any article.

The above explanation could never fully explain the rules related with English nouns. It was intended to help you understand why the mass (abstract) noun sometimes takes the definite article. For more detailed information, please read the Wikipedia article on [**Concrete nouns and abstract nouns**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Concrete_nouns_and_abstract_nouns) or you can Google many sources.

> Concrete nouns refer to physical entities that can, in principle at
>   least, be observed by at least one of the senses (for instance, chair,
>   apple, Janet or atom). Abstract nouns, on the other hand, refer to
>   abstract objects; that is, **ideas or concepts** (such as justice or
>   hatred). While this distinction is sometimes exclusive, some nouns
>   have multiple senses, including both concrete and abstract ones;
>   consider, for example, the noun art, which usually refers to a concept
>   (e.g., Art is an important element of human culture) but which can
>   refer to a specific artwork in certain contexts (e.g., I put my
>   daughter's art up on the fridge).

Note: There are exceptions which need to be learned on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @mbillard My pleasure. I am not a native English speaker and the more I learn about the articles in English, the more confused I get. :-)

Comment: 'the' is not really a determiner (it is indexical), and 'a[n]' is not really an article (it equals the determiner 'one').  The universal determiner 'all' is optional in English.  Since universals are unique, they are always definite.  English allows elision of 'the' when it is obvious.  French is less efficient.